# Custom listview adapter fail to load data in DB

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm having a strange problem when loading data from my DB to my listview. It occurs when the amount is more or less great, we talk about eg 10 data. I walk my database and I need to get the records show.

This is my adapter, I think the error is in the method getView :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);
    //Here I get my item.
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {

    }
}
```

My data's position within my activity, I ensure that the data is correct chords with multiple tests to my code, why not leave that code is extensive and difficult to explain

What happens is that it does not show all the data corresponding records but if repeated, for example:

I have 10 of my objects ids database in the following format.

```
RowItem [ id = 1 ], RowItem [ id = 2 ], RowItem [ id = 3 ],
RowItem [ id = 4 ], RowItem [ id = 5 ], RowItem [ id = 6 ],
RowItem [ id = 7 ], RowItem [ id = 8 ], RowItem [ id = 9 ],
RowItem [ id = 10 ].
```

Of these 10, the new show first and registration number 10 shows the first record, it would be in the order as follows:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
1
```

When I get the item with your position I no longer get the correct data that I wrote, not got from the DB, so I try it with the method `getItem(position)`

If it is too difficult to understand, I ask you to ask me to give more information. We can say that can obtain data from the local database or from the Internet, I come online ensure that the right data and so, but the display returns to the same, repeat the first.

Comment: dude, i suggest you to check your english, i can't undestand what you are saying.

Comment: @Gatunox Hello, sorry for my English. What happens is that I post the list of items correctly, but at the hearing (in the listview) are not loaded correctly, the first value is always repeated.